# After Nikita Den Haag, should graduate schools consider also asking for peer-student references?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

Some of you may have seen [this story](https://www.irishtimes.com/ireland/2022/06/17/russian-spy-exposed-trying-to-infiltrate-icc-studied-in-trinity/) and [the associated Tweet](https://twitter.com/eugene_finkel/status/1537501604705980417) from this infiltrator's professor - who was an unwitting author of a strong letter of recommendation for him to the ICC at The Hague.

Basically, a Russian intelligence operative had a false Brazilian identity and school record created for him by his organization. He used this to gain entrance to one respectable university for his primary degree; then used the latter to gain entrance to a top-rank graduate school of international affairs; and finally used his MA from the latter plus a "strong" letter of recommendation from an unwitting professor there to seek an internship at the ICC at The Hague - just as it starts to consider Russian actions in Ukraine.

I see no reason for Professor Finkel to feel too bad about this as he was dealing with an otherwise competent student - who just happened to have an organization creating an effective cover for him. We pay professors to teach and research, to spread enlightenment and cultivate good learning - not to suss out spies, which is the NSA's job.

But maybe after this event - which must be an embarrassment to Trinity College, Dublin and Johns Hopkins School of Advanced International Studies - we might be a little more inclined to explore some more non-traditional candidate supplementary evaluations for graduate school. Like references from fellow undergraduates for example. These would tend to show genuineness in the candidate's character, helpfulness, teamwork and "going the extra mile". These qualities *do* matter in a research group and will not be noticed much by undergraduate professors as they do not see these interactions at first hand. I realize that the dangers of small sample sizes apply here of course. Nearly everyone in a class of > 100 will have a few friends and a few enemies - and a lot they have little to do with either way due to the alphabetical ordering for class groups, social class adhesion and so on. But notes from say 2 girls *and* 2 guys saying X was always willing to help a student really stuck, this has to mean something to supervisors who seek interpersonal skills and virtues among their research group members.

How do academics here - I address academics globally, not just the US academia - feel about giving *some* weight to peer-referees of candidates *also* rather than *solely* tutor's letters and interviews by a PG Dean and the putative studies supervisor ?

Comment: Regarding the sentence *"I address academics globally, not just the US academia"* it's worth mentioning that in some parts of the world letters of recommendation are not that much of a thing, so in those places there's also no point in trying to replace the (hardly existent) letter writers with undergraduates.

Comment: @Jochen Is that the case in your state?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I live and work in Germany. I've applied for quite a number of positions (maybe 20 or so) within Germany during the last few years, and I think only for one of them I was asked to submit letters of recommendation. For some - but far from all - funding opportunities in Germany, LoRs are more relevant, but for faculty positions they have very little relevance.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of demands **on you** by students to write academic references for **their** job applications. This is what Nikita got from Prof Finkel and perhaps others in TCD. Quite a few graduate and postgraduate employers ask for this sort of academic referee letter in the lead-up to a job offer decision.

Comment: Independently of other problems with that proposal, I don't see how this would in any way be a solution to the original (IMHO rather unimportant) problem. If anything, I would expect a spy being more helpful and focused on teamwork, as any friend made in such a rather focused university-program has a reasonable chance to later end up in an important position and could thus become an exploitable source of inside information.

Comment: @mik  I am not putting this forward as a solution to espionage embarrassment. The only solution to that is to have state security procedures be more thorough. I am putting this forward as an improvement to the existing graduate school selection processes. Several contributors have commented other threads on the importance of teamwork, helping other researchers with an area of weakness, guiding younger researchers, etc as a criterion for a desirable postgrad candidate.

Comment: OK thanks, but I don't see the jump from "Russian spy" to "peer recommendations." Are we supposed to be better at sussing out imposters than professors?

Comment: The spy newspaper story (linked, if you want to read it) illustrates how classmates have a far better window on a student's character than any professor. How wise is it to provide training at an advanced international studies school to someone whose own social contact is so limited, spy or not a spy ? That's my point. And perhaps graduate school selection procedures should start to include more than just the purely academic qualifications. But please don't feel under any obligation to answer my question on the point if you simply don't care to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's not change a whole system of how we write letters of reference just because "there once was this one case". Letters of reference are written for what must surely be hundreds of thousands of cases each year, and the number of Russian spies among them is such a small fraction that I don't think it's worth changing the system for them.

Second, letters of recommendations from professors work because the letter writers put their reputation on the line when they do so. You can't write a good letter for a bad student because you're writing to your friends and colleagues, and they will be mad at you. You will hear about it at conferences and get-togethers, and it tarnishes your standing in your community. But if a student picks four other students to write for them, who cares? These students have nothing to gain from being truthful as in all likelihood they will graduate and move into industry. They can never be called out. As a consequence, there is no reason to give such letters any weight.

Finally, letters are only useful if the letter writers know the system. Professors are reasonable evaluators because they will have *seen* lots of letters and know what they need to address. Students haven't, and as a consequence they neither know what to say, nor how to say it.

Comment: I once wrote a good letter for a good student who did miserably in a doctoral program. But, I didn't know that he was dying of AIDS at the time. Sad story of course, but I had to explain things to those who received the letter.

Comment: @Wolfgang  I suggested references from a few students on the candidate's soft skills, helpfulness to other students, etc. **Not on his/her academic capabilities.**

Comment: @Trunk I did not actually say that the students had to comment on someone's *academic capabilities*. But whatever the criteria are, inexperienced writers will not know what to say.

Comment: @Wolfgang  Let's not get into a hair-splitting task here. My basic point is that even in academia one needs to consider attributes that relate more to character than actual work skills or even the extent of work output: it's a collegial environment and selection processes of today's academia ought to do more than simply *appreciate* this as something desirable - they should also seek to evaluate soft skills of grad school candidates and give this some weight IMHO. But I naturally seek other people's views on this matter, something the spy story has obliquely illuminated.

Comment: @Trunk I don't disagree that these are worthwhile criteria to consider. I just disagree that fellow students are qualified to evaluate those.

Comment: I accept that the testimony (quoted in the OP article) of the 2 students in Muller Ferreira's class is suspect as it is *after* a major news story broke. We all remember students at college who "always thought this other student X was a bit weird" - but never actually said so till after X committed some crime. But that's *human* character - something people of 22 aren't old enough to be sure of. Yet students can reasonably evaluate the student character of fellow-students as they are engaging (or not, VMF's case) with classmates for 4 years. Q1: Know if any any pilot study been done on this ?

Comment: @Trunk The point I'm making is that if a candidate chooses two other students (presumably his friends), then (i) that's not a representative choice of fellow students, (ii) these students could be asked a questionnaire, but would almost certainly not be able to write a reasonable letter, (iii) they're not neutral evaluators because they are friends of the candidate and don't have "skin in the game" because their reputation isn't on the line. -- -- What you are proposing in your last comment here is to do a representative survey of the candidate's fellow students, but that is just not feasible.

Comment: Yes. There are many perils with this. Not least the subjectivity of each student's character valuations; they'll hardly criticize another student for lack of a virtue they don't have themselves or praise one for a strength they do not yet realize is important and/or rare. Then there is the question of what is "normal" or "adequate". What is common in college campuses - vanity, attention-seeking, NPD, apathy, selfishness, etc - would not be acceptable elsewhere.